# Run unsigned Java applets

Tags: security, jre, java-applet

Basiclly the same question as [Allowing unsigned Java applications on all sites](https://superuser.com/questions/715659/allowing-unsigned-java-applications-on-all-sites), but for Java 8, where I get the pleasure of seeing this screen:

[image]

Unsurprisingly, this breaks things for me. Is there some way to work around this ludicrous decision besides installing Java 7?

Comment: +1 for excellent sarcasm in the phrase *pleasure of seeing this screen*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference [How do I control when an untrusted applet or application runs in my web browser?](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml) :

> Starting with Java 8 Update 20, the Medium security level has been removed from the Java Control Panel. Only High and Very High levels are available.
>
> **The exception site list** provides users with the option of allowing the same applets that would have been allowed by selecting the Medium option but on a site-by-site basis therefore minimizing the risk of using more permissive settings.

You may have to restart your browser for the settings to take effect.

Comment: Does the exception site list actually work for anyone else?  I've added the site my applets are on (`http://192.168.1.7/`) to the list, but they're still not running.  Is there another way around this?

Comment: Works for me :/ Are you seeing any errors in the Java console? Does http://mindprod.com/applet/wassup.html work for you?

Comment: I had to restart my browser for the Java exception settings to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I know you're looking for unsigned, but I had issues with running an app signed with MD5 with RSA.  I found the following solution worked for me, maybe it can get you started down the right path:

From https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/psa-java-8-update-131-breaks-asrocks-ipmi-virtual-console.53911/:

> all applications signed by MD5withRSA are now treated by "unapproved"
>
> but luckily you can quickly override this by updating C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_131\lib\security\java.security
>
> i've opened java.security file with notepad and made next few changes
>   (removed MD5 exclusion):
>
> jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, RSA keySize < 1024
>
> jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, DH keySize < 768, \
>       EC keySize < 224
>
> jdk.tls.legacyAlgorithms= \
>           K_NULL, C_NULL, M_NULL, \
>           DHE_DSS_EXPORT, DHE_RSA_EXPORT, DH_anon_EXPORT, DH_DSS_EXPORT, \
>           DH_RSA_EXPORT, RSA_EXPORT, \
>           DH_anon, ECDH_anon, \
>           RC4_128, RC4_40, DES_CBC, DES40_CBC, \
>           3DES_EDE_CBC, \
>       SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
>
> ig.secureValidationPolicy=\
>       disallowAlg http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116,\
>       disallowAlg http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-md5,\
>       disallowAlg http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#md5,\
>       maxTransforms 5,\
>       maxReferences 30,\
>       disallowReferenceUriSchemes file http https,\
>       minKeySize RSA 1024,\
>       minKeySize DSA 1024,\
>       noDuplicateIds,\
>       noRetrievalMethodLoops