# How to skip Java Security Prompt

Tags: windows-7, security, java

> ***NOTICE*: Finally it works adding an exception as @duDE shows in his posted Answer, basically it doesnt work before because i did it wrong.**

***The problem:***

I'm running a Java applet in my browser and it shows the following message.

[image: Valid Cert]

***What's is my Research and what i've tried?***

I have carefully searched the problem and I believe my question is unique.

There are a several question about early versions but I can't find a real solution for my current Java Version.

I have research in Google and [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/715659/allowing-unsigned-java-applications-on-all-sites) trying all the possible solutions there and nothing. The solutions I found require setting the security level to Medium in the Java Configuration, but there is no Medium security option when I attempt to change it.

[image: Java]

There was another solution pointing to the following dialog but I cannot find how to access it.

[image: Java]

Seems if I get there, I can run an application without any security pop-up/prompt.

I have also tried to put a website exception which didn't work

.

***Clarifing my Question***

**How could I skip that prompt successfully?**

I require a client-side solution.  Please take into consideration that I am not programmer, and I did not develop this Java applet.

I have Java (JRE) 8 Update 45 installed on a Windows 7 Professional x86 system.

Comment: Thanks, @Ramhound to fix my grammar issues and pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: you exposed me guys, @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 :)

Comment: In times of trouble, you find out who your friends are ;))

Comment: @duDE, is simply it works, i did not sleeping very well, maybe i've typed something wrong, ty to point me to the right direction and for your fast reply. i hope my question help more ppl facing same issue without sleep problems ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you can simply add the application URL to the Exception list: [How can I configure the Exception Site List?](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/exception_sitelist.xml)

```
Click on the Edit Site List button.
Click the Add in the Exception Site List window.
Click in the empty field under Location field to enter the URL.
URL should begin with http:// or https://
eg. http://myexample.com or https://myexample.com
Click OK to save the URL that you entered. If you click Cancel, the URLs are not saved.
Click Continue on the Security Warning dialog.
```

[image]

Comment: ty @duDe for your fast reply(sounds as we are close friends) i'll try this but first ill do a clean install of my Java again and it's because i've tried this before without success, that do not mean you are wrong, there is a 99% chance that I'm wrong. i'll tell you the update.

Comment: @Ramhound the entry was there, but i've removed before a couple tries.

Comment: @Ramhound updated.

Comment: This, plus -> Long term, poke the app developer to update to the latest Java security requirements.  It's a little painful (I'm a dev and had to do it to a few apps), but users are much happier not having to work around Java security!

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch, i have no comments about that developer, it uses case tools to build the code, your warning is very useful but saldy the provider is not very skilled, well is not my problem, i didnt signed the contract anyway :D